# PS4 controller turns off upon sign in

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

So my controller will turn and stay on fine, but as soon as I choose an account to sign in as, the controller turns off. It will also turn off if I press the PlayStation button. Basically it functions as a normal controller until I try to sign in, then it turns off automatically. Also, if it has a charge, it will turn itself on automatically. I've tried resetting and the share+PS button combo. Neither worked. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Narrow down which end the fault lies - controller or PS4 - by doing the following:

1.) Try using the controller and pairing it with another / different PS4.

2.) Try pairing a different PS4 controller to the PS4 in question.

- If the fault is the controller, I'd suggest replacing it.
- If the fault lies in the unit, note the BT receiver is near the HDD.

Other Solutions:

- Is your unit vertical? Lay it flat and try again.
- Is it in an enclosed space and near another devices BT device? Try disabling the BT on nearby devices. The PS4 could be booting your controller because another device is unexpectedly paired.